# Flash ESP32 with USB to TTL Converter

Tags: microcontroller

I am trying to flash an ESP32 Module that is on a custom PCB, and I am unsure about the hardware I will need.

The interface to the ESP32 looks like the four pin header shown below.

Am I supposed to use one of those USB to TTL converters, or how do I go about flashing the microcontroller?

[image]

Diagram of UART interface

[image]

Comment: esp-prog is like $20, and the schematic is available free, if you can't afford to buy one just copy the UART half of it

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could use an ESP-PROG or similar, but it also needs a line to the EN gpio and GPIO0. The latter is not perse necessary, but makes life easy: otherwise you have to press boot/reset buttons every time you flash. You could use the same connector as for the ESP-PROG or use a Tag-Connect (smaller and by using a footprint on the PCB no component necessary)

Comment: the 1,27mm pitch header also available on the  ESP-prog is about the same size as the tag connect landing zone